# Integrating Dialogflow WebDemo in website?

Tags: javascript, html

I have integrated the bot in the website but the issue is,  when the user gives the answer and press the enter then I should call the API. So, how to find that user presses the enter?

```
<div id="myModal1" class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content chat-box">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Bot</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" onclick="closeModal1()">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            <iframe
            allow="microphone;"
            width="350"
            height="430"
            src="">
        </iframe>
        </iframe>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You can write a custom function to the onClick event. Or you can send the request  inside the `closeModal()` function.

Comment: @SifatHaque -  I tried to add onClick even to the iframe tag but it is not considering the method which I have mentioned in the onClick and also I don't want in closeModal() function

Comment: can you share a real demo of your issue? You can create a working environment in codeSandbox.

Comment: @SifatHaque - When I say hi and presses enter it is showing default welcome intent message which I have mentioned in Dialogflow prompts section and started giving another triggering word so that other intent trigger name "early". It starts asking the prompts which are in that intent now what I need is when the user says the answer to every prompt I need to call the function.